# Подчеркивание нескольких подстрок в JTextPane

Tags: java

Я делаю в программе поле для ввода (JTextPane) с проверкой правописания. И хочу сделать подчеркивание у каждого слова, к которому есть варианты замены. Как я могу подчеркнуть несколько различных подстрок в тексте?

В потоке проверки правописания я выполняю следующий код:

```
for (RuleMatch match : matches) {
    if (match.getToPos() <= text.length() && match.getFromPos() >= 0) {
        JTextPane inputField = ((JTextPane) jTextPane);
        inputField.setText(text);
        inputField.setCaretPosition(position);

        StyledDocument doc = inputField.getStyledDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setUnderline(keyWord, Boolean.TRUE);

        doc.setCharacterAttributes(match.getFromPos(), match.getToPos() - match.getFromPos(), keyWord, true);
    }
}
```

Но этот код подчеркивает только последнюю опечатку из цикла.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать такое же подчеркивание, но в нескольких участках JTextPane?

Comment: Или, возможно, в Java есть какой-то другой класс для текстовых полей, где это поддерживается?